# Доступ к своим папкам/файлам wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, cms, доступ

Есть папка с набором js/html/php файлов, который уже выполняют нужный мне функционал (обновление базы). 
Закинул папку на хост сайтом на WP, но при попытке открыть файл, или получить доступ, **САЙТ** отвечает что такой страницы нет, именно сайт, а не сервер. 
Вот и **САМ** вопрос: что сделать чтобы я мог свободно зайти по адресу типа: mysitename.dn/calc-setting/index.html

PS - пытался настраивать .htaccess в корне хоста, а также в нужной папке, но результатов не дало (возможно не правильно настраивал)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> САЙТ отвечает что такой страницы нет, именно сайт, а не сервер

При использовании сайтов, которые, в свою очередь, используют `mod_rewrite`, это обычное поведение, так как все запросы там, в случае, **если не существует такой папки или файла**, к которым вы обращаетесь, перенаправляются на файл `index.php`. Вот обычный `.htaccess` для `WP` (4.8):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
# если мы не нашли файл, который запрашивается, то правило ниже выполнится
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# если мы не нашли папку, которая запрашивается, то правило ниже выполнится
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Попробуйте, например, запросить какую-нибудь картинку из установленных у вас тем, и вы увидите, как она отдастся без проблем. Путь должен выглядеть примерно так: `http://your-site.com/wp-content/themes/your-theme/assets/images/header.jpg`.

> пытался настраивать .htaccess в корне хоста, а также в нужной папке

Если у вас ничего не менялось в корневом .htaccess, то делать это не нужно, если только ваш код также не требует каких-то особых правил обработки.

> что сделать чтобы я мог свободно зайти по адресу типа:
>   mysitename.dn/calc-setting/index.html

Для этого, обычно, нужно всего лишь убедиться, что вы обращаетесь по именно тому пути, по которому лежат ваши реальные файлы.

Comment: Я убирал вообще все строки из .htaccess и точно обращаюсь по существующему пути, но получаю, то что получаю. :( 
Может это из за того что там стоит тема огромная?

Comment: Дополните свой вопрос структурой папок вашего сайта (можно скрин из файлового менеджера, раскрыв папки до интересующей вас) и запросом, который вы пытаетесь сделать к этой папке.

Comment: Сделал скрины .htaccess который сейчас, ftp, и открытого адреса.
http://savepic.ru/14602023.png
http://savepic.ru/14592807.png
http://savepic.ru/14597927.png

Comment: @КириллШрейдер Попробуйте убрать строку 8 в файле .htaccess

Comment: Убрал, ничего не изменилось всё также. 
Это кстати те настройки которые я делал, по сути из-за этого я должен был получить доступ, но не получил.

Comment: @КириллШрейдер тогда это достаточно странно. Убедитесь, что используется именно тот путь в браузере, который и на веб-сервере - скопируйте его в файловом менеджере и вставьте в браузере после имени вашего сайта. Возможно, где-то использована русская буква, например в слове `calc` одна из `c` написана кириллицей.

Comment: Да я даже не руками пишу адрес, а просто копирую и вставляю, так что ошибок там не может быть. 
Я поэтому то и обратился сюда, потому что сам ума не приложу в чём проблема! :(

Comment: @КириллШрейдер а что насчет открытия какой-нибудь картинки, как я в ответе написал - открываются?

Comment: Приношу свои извинения за свою тупость. :) 
Заказчик дал FTP с полной копией сайта, но не на том домене. :( 
Так что мне всё правильно сайт отвечал, что файлов нет.

Comment: @КириллШрейдер проверка на идентичность данных в вебе и на хостинге была следующей после того, как вы бы убедились, что картинка из темы открывается ;) Ну или она бы и показала, что того файла, который вы хотели открыть, на самом деле нет, а значит вы смотрите на разное.